# Fractional derivative definition

Tags: integration, derivatives, fractional-calculus

Suppose that $f(x) \in C^1$ for a $x \in [a, x]$. Then a regularization of Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative is defined as:

$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-b)} \frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x}\left( \mathrm{f}\left( t\right) -\mathrm{f}\left( a\right) \right) \,\left( \frac{d}{d\,t}\,\left( -\frac{{\left( x-t\right) }^{1-b}}{1-b}\right) \right) dt
$

assuming $0<b \leq 1$.

Is this definition equivalent to the Caputo definition?
$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-b)} \int_{a}^{x}\frac{ \mathrm{f^\prime}\left( t\right) }{{\left( x-t\right) }^{b}}dt
$

(As suggested ) here is the calculation:
The first step is to integrate by parts:

$
I= \frac{\int_{a}^{x}\left( \frac{d}{d\,t}\,\left( \mathrm{f}\left( t\right) -\mathrm{f}\left( a\right) \right) \right) \,{\left( x-t\right) }^{1-b}dt}{1-b}
- \left. \frac{\left( \mathrm{f}\left( t\right) -\mathrm{f}\left( a\right) \right) \,{\left( x-t\right) }^{1-b}}{1-b}\right|_{t=x}
+\left. \frac{\left( \mathrm{f}\left( t\right) -\mathrm{f}\left( a\right) \right) \,{\left( x-t\right) }^{1-b}}{1-b}\right|_{t=a}
$.

Since $0<b \leq 1$ the second term vanishes. The third  term also vanishes. Then we are left with:

$
I = \frac{\int_{a}^{x}\left( \frac{d}{d\,t}\,\mathrm{f}\left( t\right) \right) \,{\left( x-t\right) }^{1-b}dt}{1-b}
$

Finally, differentiating gives

$  \frac{d}{d\,x}\,I = \int_{a}^{x}\frac{ \mathrm{f^{\prime}}\left( t\right) }{{\left( x-t\right) }^{b}}dt
$.

So applying also the factor yields Caputo's definition.

Comment: try integration "by parts"

Comment: I did. If I post the calculation will you check it?

Comment: yes, if you post the calculation we can maybe see where your difficulty occurs

Answer (score 0):

The regularization is clear if you write out the Riemann-Liouville derivative $^{RL}D^{\beta}_a$ and the Caputo derivative $^{C}D^{\beta}_a$  in their generator forms (which can be obtain by integrating by parts the definitions involving the Riemann-Liouville integrals)
\begin{align}
^{RL}D^{\beta}_af(x)&= \int_0^{a-x}(f(x+y)-f(x))\nu(y)dy &-f(x)\int_{a-x}^\infty\nu(y)dy,\\
^{C}D^{\beta}_a f(x)&= \int_0^{a-x}(f(x+y)-f(x))\nu(y)dy &+(f(a)-f(x))\int_{a-x}^\infty\nu(y)dy.
\end{align}
where $\nu(y):=\frac{-\Gamma(-\beta)^{-1}}{y^{1+\beta}}$, and $x<a$. 
Also these two representations have very natural and nice probabilistic interpretation.